# Reading a hidden text in Word

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I use the following to read hidden text.

```
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.TextRetrievalMode.IncludeHiddenText = true;
var Text = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.Text;
```

But it doesn't return hidden text. Moreover, if I check TextRetrievalMode.IncludeHiddenText, it's still false - my statement is ignored but it doesn't throw any exception.

How to read hidden text please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the text retrieval mode like in your sample will always return a fresh `Range` object with the default configuration. You need to get a range object, set the `TextRetrievalMode` on that object and then get the text from that same object:

```
var range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range();
range.TextRetrievalMode.IncludeHiddenText = true;
var text = range.Text;
```